# How to solve memory error in docker container in linux, for error `was sent SIGKILL! Perhaps out of memory?`

Tags: python, docker, memory, devops

[image]
I run the application on the docker, it gives an error. There is no memory limit, in `docker stats` it shows that 32gb of memory is available. But the container behaves strangely at startup, although 32gb is available, it does not reach 10gb in use, it gives an error with about 9gb of memory. This means that it does not reach 10gb.
[image]

How do I solve my memory limitation problem?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can check to resolve the problem:
1.

> docker run --memory=16g [container_name]

Or for docker-compose  file:

> mem_limit: 16g

2. 

Check Docker events by below command for any memory related issue:

> docker events

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried it that way, it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

[image]
helps me adding timeout parameter

`gunicorn src.app:app --workers 2 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --timeout 1000 --bind 0.0.0.0:${APP_PORT}`

`--timeout 1000`